# java.time.Instant.now has more precision in java 11 compared to java 8 and how to get backward compatible

Tags: java, java-time, backwards-compatibility

I've below code in java

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.JodaModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;
import java.time.Instant;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        Instant instant = Instant.now();
        System.out.println("java version " + System.getProperty("java.version"));
        System.out.println("java vendor " + System.getProperty("java.vendor"));
//        System.out.println(instant.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLIS));
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, true);
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(instant));
    }

}
```

when I run with java 8 I get below output -

```
java version 1.8.0_352
java vendor Azul Systems, Inc.
2023-07-15T07:27:49.588Z
```

when I run with java 11 I get below output -

```
java version 11.0.17
java vendor Azul Systems, Inc.
2023-07-15T07:08:15.457153Z
```

It is clearly java 11 has more precision than java 8 and it is causing schema change in the middleware downstream.

Is there any way to make this api call backward compatible?

Comment: Please explain how this is causing a schema change. Are you asking how to get `Instant.toString()` to print the same number of digits? Or something else?

Comment: In Java 21 there are *nine* digits after the decimal point. And are you certain that there are double quotes around the result in Java 8?

Comment: You can truncate the instant, for example with `truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLIS)`.

Comment: @tgdavies sorry my editing mistake I added double quotes and I removed it after your comment

Comment: Can you also clarify what "make this api call backward compatible" actually means? Which API call? What incompatibility are you finding?

Comment: @tgdavies I updated for backward compatible

Comment: I still don't understand exactly how non-zero trailing digits in `Instant.getNano()` break your code.

Comment: I updated the code which converts instant to string and that is sent downstream

Comment: OK, then Sweeper's or Mark's answer should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a `String` with 3 digits of fractional seconds, you can make your own `DateTimeFormatter` and format the `Instant` with that:

```
// note that there are only 3 "S"
var formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
    .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
System.out.println(formatter.format(Instant.now()));
```

This will always produce 3 digits after the decimal dot, even if they are all 0.

If you actually want an `Instant` that is rounded to the nearest millisecond, use `truncatedTo`:

```
System.out.println(Instant.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLIS));
```

[`Instant.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#toString()) will use *at most* 3 decimal places for such `Instant`s. `Instant.toString` uses the [`ISO_INSTANT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT) formatter.